# What is the frictional resistance of a perfect spinning sphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

Imagine a **perfect** sphere rotating around an axis that is in line with a uniform gravitational field in space (no air resistance / angular drag) where its infinitely small contact point is on a plane where the coefficient of friction between the sphere and the plane is 1.

Would it experience any friction and if so, how does the formular for it look like?

Furthermore if the rotational axis was orthogonal to the gravitational field, then to my understanding it would move aka roll if and only if there was some friction, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For friction to arise some *contact area* between both objects must exist (because friction is caused by interaction between matter of both surfaces)

In the case of a perfect and perfectly rigid sphere and a perfect and perfectly hard surface, there cannot be such a contact area, only a point-like contact.

That means that in both your **hypothetical scenarios** there can be no friction between sphere and surface. For the second scenario it means the sphere would not start rolling (your understanding is correct).

Comment: So if the object was placed on a slope in regards to the gravitational field, it would slide down the slope instead of roll correct?

Comment: Yes, precisely. No rolling w/o friction.

Comment: Not sure that's the right way to think about it because the friction between two surfaces does not depend on the area of the contact patch: It only depends on the material properties of the surfaces and, on the normal force between them. So, as the area of the contact patch approaches zero, the friction remains constant. You could argue that that tells us nothing about the case where the area of the contact patch actually _is_ zero, but I would argue that that is an un-physical case, and we should not be asking Physics what happens in that case.

Comment: @SolomonSlow   I appreciate that we have something like a paradox here, in the sense that *zero surface* cannot be physical. I did raise that point.

Comment: While that is true you could argue that even a perfect sphere might have a contact surface where the surface area is equal to some epsillon which is infinitely close to but not zero. Since a perfect sphere is a hypothetical object, I should have specified or concretised the sorounding factors more, indeed.